# Azure Cloud Service uses a different nuget package path than its worker role

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-cloud-services

I have a .net47 azure cloudservice referencing my .netstandard libraries.

those libraries use `System.Data.SqlClient` and `System.Reflection.TypeExtesions` which I included to my worker role with nuget.

for some reason I am getting a `BadImageFormatException` - after a quick search I found out that the `approot` folder of the cloudservice contains a different version of `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` and `System.Reflection.TypeExtesions.dll` than the `bin/debug` folder of the WorkerRole project (The size is different, also using a powershell script I was able to load the latter but not the first -- same BadImageFormatException).

copying the dlls from bin/debug to the approot fixes the issue - but this isn't a good fix.

I have no idea what could cause this version mismatch - since it seems to me that the cloudservice would just copy the dlls from bin/debug

**both projects are compiled and released in debug for the time being

### Update

I was able to figure out that the cloud service, and the worker role class library are taking the nuget dll from two different paths where the first one doesn't work -

```
%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\System.Data.SqlClient\4.4.0\ref\net461\System.Data.SqlClient.dll
%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\System.Data.SqlClient\4.4.0\runtimes\win\lib\net461\System.Data.SqlClient.dll
```

deleting .nuget folder doesn't resolve this issue - seems like some weird configuration issue that causes the cloud service to be resolved with a different package than the csproj itself

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this same issue as well but only on projects using the Worker role, not projects using the Web role. The Web role cloud service project on build copies the source web project bin directory to the cloud service project bin directory.

We emulated the copying of the source project bin directory to the cloud service bin directory and found that to work. To do this we added a AfterBuild Msbuild step in the Cloud Service ccproj file to do the copying.

**A better work around was posted here**:
[https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3699#issuecomment-612306965](http://Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets%20in%20combination%20with%20PackageReference%20resolves%20ref%20target)

This should be added to your source project csproj file:

```
 <Target 
     Name="BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies" 
     DependsOnTargets="$(BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependenciesDependsOn)"
     Returns="@(BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependency)">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependency Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(FullPath)');
                                                  @(ReferenceDependencyPaths->'%(FullPath)');
                                                  @(NativeReferenceFile->'%(FullPath)');
                                                  @(_DeploymentLooseManifestFile->'%(FullPath)');
                                                  @(ResolvedIsolatedComModules->'%(FullPath)')"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```